# Issues loading array from file ino jQuery array

Tags: jquery

I'm having issues loading an array from a file from $.get(). I get a good HTTP status code so the file is accessed, but it's not turning it into an array.

Here's the code I have

```
$(function() {

    $.get('https://gist.github.com/storbeck/6956620/raw/e274c8af60ef25e7bc481fded0c9e4e8e8412e75/testdata', function(data) {
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {      

            rangeSelector : {
                selected : 1
            },

            title : {
                text : 'Test Data'
            },

            series : [{
                name : 'Data',
                data : data,
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                }
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HCzXG/) of the current code of it not working.

I was able to get it working by copy/pasting the array into the data variable and not using $.get so I don't think the array is the problem. Here's [that version](http://jsfiddle.net/HCzXG/1/)

One other thing I'm having issues with is the epoch time in Highcharts, when I test the time in an online convertor, it converts the time just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting an empty result because 
the page you are trying to load has `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header
that limits who can remotely load the page.
Neither $.ajax, $.post, $.get will load this page because they are blocked.

If you load your script into your local browser you will see in your browser console log:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load
https://gist.github.com/storbeck/6956620/raw/e274c8af60ef25e7bc481fded0c9e4e8e8412e75/testdata.
Origin http://www.yourdomain.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Answer (score 0):

its a Same-Origin-Policy problem...

If you have access to the file, that generates the data, you could use `JSONP`, the data should be formatted with a callback function.
If you have access to the server you could add something like this:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ...
```

But the only way that might work for you, is to get the result first with a `PHP, ASP` or whatever script, and then call that script with your ajax. But this should be on the same domain ofc.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)

One way you could work around this is by requesting the file on your server, where there aren't issues about this, and then making the ajax GET call to your server:

*Create a new page on your server, and request the gist file in that page and return its content as the response. Of course, you need dynamic pages for this to work*

*Change the endpoint in your jQuery `$.get` to that page, for example: `www.mydomain.com/highchartvalues`*

*Profit*